# I have a height problem (with my switching regulator on a height constrained PCB)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator, electrolytic-capacitor, ceramic, tantalum

I was planning to use this [part (datasheet)](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp3063-d.pdf)  (basically MC34063 with thermal shutdown,) but I don´t have enough room above the PCB.
I need to keep the components under 2.2mm.

According to my calculation I need like 70uF in Cout.

I was going to use a tantalum capacitor, but then I read on page 9 in the datasheet:

*"Capacitor CO should be a low equivalent series resistance (ESR)
**electrolytic** designed for switching regulator applications."*

Can I use a tantalum with low ESR instead? What is "low"? Under 3 ohm? Under 1 ohm? Or 300mohm?

Is it better to use ceramic, or do Ihave to use electrolytic?  (It is hard to find short electrolytics.)

Comment: The question title kind of sounds like you (personally) are too tall. Unless that was your intention, let's rename the question to something like "Switching regulator on a height constrained PCB."

Comment: The SOIC-8 package dimension table in your datasheet claims the height (C) of the IC to be just 1.75 mm. Isn't that OK?

Comment: it´s not the height of the IC but of the capacitor that is the problem.

Comment: With a more modern switching IC having higher switching frequency, you'll be able to shrink both the inductor and input/output caps and use all ceramic caps.

Comment: Shrink in size or capacitance? can tantalum work also?

Comment: You should be able to get 70uF in 1206 ceramic or maybe even 0805. "Low ESR" likely just means it should have reasonable low ESR even at the switching frequency of the regulator.

Comment: higher frequency means lower capacitance and inductance value, therefore smaller packages. Capacitors are less of a problem because you can use several thin ceramics, but MC34063 needs a bit large inductance value, did you find one that fits your height requirement?

Comment: What's the input and output voltages and currents?

Comment: @akwky I like a nice humorous (but clear) title :)

Comment: Get it platform shoes? Like Elton John in Tommy  https://youtu.be/H_r_dWenKhk

Comment: Vin 3.3V and Vout 13V max 55 mAmp.   Cap I was looking at CL31A226MOCLNNC at the momemt. cheap and quite big Capacitance. Not sure what ESR it has.. I am running the "MC34063" at 100 kHz

Comment: Low ESR means T= ESR*C < 10us in e-caps and. << 1/f sw

Comment: _"this part (datasheet) (basically MC34063 with thermal shutdown,) but I don´t have enough room above the PCB"_ Here you are referring to the height of the MC34063, but later you talk about the capacitor height. Please clarify.

Comment: "Vin 3.3V and Vout 13V" You're using this as a boost converter? This has a darlington BJT switch, with 1V minimum VceSat, at only 3.3V input, that'll eat 30% of your efficiency...

Comment: Incidentally, tantalum capacitors are also electrolytic. The ones you're probably thinking of are specifically aluminum electrolytics--for some reason, "aluminum electrolytic" commonly gets shortened to "electrolytic", while "tantalum electrolytic" gets shortened to "tantalum".

Comment: winny: true, maybe I was not so clear.. I just mentioned the boost regulator used. The questions is about the capacitor.

Comment: bobflux: maybe its old and bad Circuit. But cheap and easy to source was my thinking. What would you have used instead?

Comment: Bobflux: yes, I found one inductor that is low enough

Comment: Thank you all for the comments!

Answer (score 4):

'Low' is probably in the 10 mΩ range. The design does not need ESR to be above a certain value.

That IC was designed before large ceramic capacitors (MLCC) were available or practical. Now they are practical and suitable for this part.

Comment: sorry for newbie question: One would want the ESR to be low because of heat? or something else?  but high for some regulators because of some something with the control loop?    correct?   you mention ceramic. But can low ESR tantalum work?

Comment: Is there such a thing as "too low" ESR? I'd swear I saw a (linear?) regulator which was only stable in certain "envelope".

Comment: With old style LDOs, you can have too low ESR, for stability. New style LDOs should be able to cope with ceramics. With a switcher, lowest ESR is good, for ripple. Beware, ceramic capacitors, especially large values in small packages, may only deliver 20-30% of their advertised capacitance at their rated voltage. It sucks but it's true, high-K ceramics usually have a vicious voltage coefficient, which together with tempco and tolerance can leave you with waaay less capacitance than you thought.

Comment: @Neil_UK, spot on with the ceramic capacitor warning. MLCC capacitance in certain parts varies dramatically with applied voltage and it's a lesser-known characteristic in industry.

Comment: so if at the rated max voltage they lose 20% to 30% : at what voltage are they using for the advertised capacitance? any special voltage or just what gives the most capacitance?

Comment: @mistermister, they go to 20..30% - so they lose 70..80%. Look in the datasheets of an X5R capacitor, you can find one online yourself, and look at the graph there.

Comment: Generally the C is measured at 0V which is the highest C value. Different dielectrics (X5R, X7R) have different C(V) characteristics. This is not really misleading specs, but a general characteristic of MLCC structures.